# Why doesn't my TV display my computer's HDMI output, only under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hdmi, multiple-monitors

I am trying to connect my PC to my TV via HDMI. It works fine under Ubuntu, but it's not working under Windows 7 (32-bit).

The video card is an ATI 4670, the TV is a Philips 74xx series and the monitor is a Dell 19" model that connects to the PC via VGA.

The TV receives signal and shows picture while the PC is booting (i.e. during the BIOS self-check and the Windows 7 logo). However, the TV says there is no signal after the Windows login screen comes up.

I have installed the latest CCC and ATI video card driver. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: is the pc a laptop?

Comment: @KronoS, it's a pc

Comment: for fun have you tried connecting just the TV to the computer, to see if it will work on its own?

Comment: @Xantec, thanks. I'll try this. But both monitor and tv could show the pc's picture if using Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have your desktop extended or cloned to the tv? If not it will just shut off the TV when Windows boots.

Comment: Is your resolution in range? i.e does the TV support the resolution Windows is set to run at on your pc?

Comment: Yes, the resolution of tv is the supported resolution listed in the spec.

Comment: I can't find your tv on the philips website (only 76xx models) but if it supports VGA, did you try connecting your pc through VGA yet?

Comment: I know the card uses an ATI chip, but who actually made the card? e.g. ASUS, Sapphire, etc.

Comment: @Yohsoog, I can't remember the exact model of my TV. It has the VGA port, but I didn't try it.

Comment: @Tog, the manufacturer of video card is dataland that locates in China Mainland.

Comment: @Kane and can/will you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably is caused by the manufacturer of video card.

I bought a new vide card(ATI 5450 series), which works well.

Answer (score 2):

Press the (Windows key + P) to change from the 4 different ways to use multiple monitors/projectors; it could be that you are using it in computer only mode. Since you did mention that Ubuntu shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look in the resolution settings etc and ensure that output to the additional screen is enabled. Display->Settings. Both screens should be visible in the both, but one may not be set up for use.

If you can not see both, try using the "detect" button.

Comment: it's weird. The CCC or windows 7 could detect the tv as the second monitor when the power of tv is off. It won't detect the tv when turning on the tv or switching to the signal source to hdmi.

Comment: Have you tried switching through the different HDMI signal sources?

Comment: When connecting to the PC is it via a DVI connector?

Comment: Tried switching different HDMI signal source, but it doesn't work. The video card supports VGA, DVI and HDMI output. Currently HDMI connects with tv, VGA connects with 19' Dell monitor. I don't have DVI cable, so no chance to try connect pc monitor via DVI.